# Determine whether it's a vector subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a hard time understanding the question, that my math-prof gave it to me. The question is about proving whether the below given construct

$$ \{ f \in V \mid \exists B \geq 0 \forall a \in \mathbb{R}: |f(a)| \leq B \} $$

is a vector subspace, where $V = \mathcal{F}(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})$

I tried to understand the question, and I kinda proved it, that the given construct is in fact a vector subspace. But I have no idea, if it's true, or not.
Any help is appreciated.

Let $|f(a)|$ and $|g(a)|$ element of $V$

Addition: $|f(a)| + |g(a)|$ (According to Definition: $|f(a)| \leq B$) which means $\Rightarrow |f(a)| + |g(a)| \leq B$

Let $\lambda$ element of $\mathbb{R}$

$$ \lambda \times |f(a)| \leq B \times \lambda $$

(According to Definition: $|f(a)| \leq B$) which means $\Rightarrow \lambda \times (\leq B) \leq \lambda times B$

Comment: What does $\mathcal F(\mathbb R, \mathbb R)$ mean?

Comment: Hint: if $|f| \le B_1$ and $|g| \le B_2$, then $|f+g| \le B_1 + B_2$, and $|\lambda f| \le |\lambda| B_1$.

Comment: $|f(a)|$ is not an element of $V$:  $f$ is.

Comment: I've converted your post to MathJax. Click Edit to see how it looks, and please check out the [help on formatting](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is a vector space, but not for those reasons. I will denote your space by $\mathcal B$.

First of all, you must check that $\mathcal B$ is not empty. Easy: just take the null function.

Then you must prove that if $f,g\in\mathcal B$, then $f+g\in\mathcal B$. There are numbers $B_f$ and $B_g$ such that$$(\forall a\in\Bbb R):|f(a)|\leqslant B_f\text{ and }|g(a)|\leqslant B_g.$$But then$$(\forall a\in\Bbb R):|(f+g)(a)|=|f(a)+g(a)|\leqslant|f(a)|+|g(a)|\leqslant B_f+B_g.$$So, $f+g$ is bounded.

Finally, you must prove that if $\lambda\in\Bbb R$ and $f\in\mathcal B$, then $\lambda f\in\mathcal B$ too. Take a number $B$ such that$$(\forall a\in\Bbb R):|f(a)|\leqslant B.$$Then$$(\forall a\in\Bbb R):|\lambda f(a)|=|\lambda||f(a)|\leqslant|\lambda|B,$$and therefore $\lambda f$ is bounded too.